# Authorization Required This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Приветствую гуру!
Столкнулся с одной проблемой.
Есть два домена, первый находится по адресу

> /home/user/domains/first.ru/public_html

второй по адресу

> /home/user/domains/second.ru/public_html

С first.ru на second.ru идет редирект 301:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Как мы видим, мы хотим, чтоб нас перенаправляли на second.ru с first.ru, если в адресе не указана папка folder1 или folder2.
Такой пример прекрасно работает.

Понадобилось на folder2 поставить пароль.
Поставил стандартными средствами панелью управления хостингом DirectAdmin.
В папке second.ru сформировался файл .htaccess со следующим содержанием:

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/domains/second.ru/.htpasswd/public_html/folder2/.htpasswd
AuthName "Hello world!"
require valid-user
AuthType Basic
```

Всё вроде хорошо, но при запуске происходит редирект на second.ru с оговоркой:

> Authorization Required This server
> could not verify that you are
> authorized to access the document
> requested. Either you supplied the
> wrong credentials (e.g., bad
> password), or your browser doesn't
> understand how to supply the
> credentials required.

На second.ru есть такая же папка, но в ней ничего нет, так как я перенес содержимое к домену first.ru из-за этой же проблемы!!!
По сути редирект нужен для склейки доменов, чтоб second.ru считался поисковиками главным/основным!
На домене second.ru тоже есть файл .htaccess со следующим содержанием:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value default_charset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html|htm)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ http://second.ru/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?third.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?fourth.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?fifth.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sixth.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?seventh.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.second\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([method]+)/?$ http://m.second.ru/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([method]+)/([admin]+)/?$ http://m.second.ru/admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([likes]+)/?$ /$1/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([as]+)/?$ /$1/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([to]+)/?$ /$1/index.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([go]+)/?$ /$1/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^([subdomain1]+)/?$ http://subdomain1.second.ru/index.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([subdomain2]+)/?$ http://subdomain2.second.ru/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ ?moduls=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ?moduls=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([gallery]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ ?moduls=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([comment]+)/([-0-9]+)/?$ ?moduls=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([tech]+)/([-0-9]+)/?$ ?moduls=$1&id=$2 [NC]
###
```

Это ЧПУ, переадресация с www на без www, добавление слэша в конце адресной строки если отсутствует и т.д.

Почему происходит конфликт???
Комментирую require valid-user

```
#require valid-user
```

...работает, но не авторизовывает (это понятно)

убираю редирект который находится в корне, тогда работает авторизация, но не происходит редирект если просто набрать first.ru!!!

Поясните пожалуйста, что за проблема?
И как её решить мирным путем =)

Спасибо!

Comment: это точно правильно ? /home/user/domains/second.ru/**.htpasswd**/public_html/folder2/.htpasswd

Comment: Да, в первом случае это папка, во втором файл!
Так строит авторизацию панель управления DirectAdmin и она работает, правда когда в корне закомментировать основной .htaccess а именно редирект!

Comment: т.е. вы используете directAdmin и правите конфиги при этом вручную ? в общем откажитесь от гибкости или от красивости.

Comment: При чем тут конфиги? Какие конфиги? Директадмин это лишь инструмент создать файл .htaccess и .htpasswd с нужными данными!!!
Еще раз поясняю...
На основном аккаунте нужен редирект кроме двух папок!
Т.е. когда заходят в папку folder1 и/или folder2 чтоб не происходил 301 редирект!
Для остальных обращений нужен редирект 301!

Пробовал в папках folder1 и folder2 прописывать: RewriteEngine off
Не помогает(